# Is there any command to know which script.sh produced certain file in UNIX?

Tags: unix

For example, I got in the same file like `script1.sh , script2.sh` then I have an `output.vcf` (bioinformatics stuff but is guess it doesnt matter). Then I am sure one of those scripts created the output file but i don't know which of them.

Is there any way to figure it out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO post factum you can't get this information. But each UNIX have own audit subsystem and if you activate it you can get which file operation (in this case file creation) is done by which program  (shell script).

Actually there is a way. You can browse the scripts and search for the filename in question. There will be a problem if both scripts have this filename.